Black and white series with an episode about the hunchback of Notre Dame
I have been going crazy trying to figure out the name of an old series I watched as a kid in the 80's.
It could be originally from a different time period.  It was a horror / thriller mystery series that started out showing a house in the rain with candles light in the window (I think.)  Then it goes into an episode.  I do remember one episode was about Quasimodo, hunchback of Notre Dame, but that's all I can remember.

I did a search for "Twilight Zone Quasimodo" and this turned up: "Way Out"

The black-and-white show would begin with what became its signature image, a slow pan over a series of mist-shrouded, disembodied hands, before resting on one which would burst into flames at the title came onscreen. Then, flexing his dry British charm like a more cosmopolitan Vincent Price, Dahl would give a short intro to each episode.

and

In the episode False Face, an actor pays a deformed homeless man to be his model for some Quasimodo make-up, but the effects turn out to be a bit too real.

